# Clone array of object but with selected properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following two interface defined:

```
interface BarProp {
    Item: Foo[];
    Date: string;
}

interface Foo {
    Name: string;
    Date: string;
    IsValid: boolean;
}
```

I'm trying to do two things:

- Clone `BarProp.Item` array but only with the properties Name and Date
- In this cloned array, add a new property if `IsValid` is `true`

I have implemented the following and it works. But I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

```
// First create a new array by mapping over `Items` with only `Name` and `Date`
const newItemsArray = BarProp.Items.map((i) => {
    return {
        Name: i.Name,
        Date: i.Date,
    };
});

//loop over this new array and conditionally add `New Property`    
for (let i = 0; i < newItemsArray.length; i++) {
    if (BarProps.Items[i].IsValid) {
        newItemsArray[i].NewProperty = "New Property";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

edit:

proposed change:

```
const newItemsArray = BarProp.Items.map((i, index) => {
    if (i.IsValid) {
        Name: i.Name,
        Date: i.Date,
        NewProperty: "NewProperty",
    } else {
        Name: i.Name,
        Date: i.Date,
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate twice, you can assign the property directly in the map loop, using the index. Is `props` the array you need to check for?

Comment: @briosheje note that I only want `NewProperty` if IsValid is true. I've updated original post with a proposed change. please have a look.

Comment: Please provide further informations about what `props.Items` is. Is it a different array? is it just a typo and meant to be `BarProp.Items`? The proposed change logic is correct anyway, though the syntax is wrong.

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Maybe look at using lambda to iterate the collection of items to a new instance of the object type..

Comment: Oops, typo. Its the same as `BarProps.Items`.

Comment: @MartinM no it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need this, it doesn't sound extremely reasonable to me, but you can make that in a single loop.

You can take advantage of `Object.assign` to create a new object in a single shot according to whether `IsValid` is true or not.

```
// First create a new array by mapping over `Items` with only `Name` and `Date`
const newItemsArray = BarProp.Items.map((i) => {
    return Object.assign({
        Name: i.Name,
        Date: i.Date
    }, i.IsValid ? {
        NewProperty: 'New Property'
    }: {});
});
```

Once again, this doesn't sound as a great design choice whatsoever, but if that's somehow, somewhere, needed, it's a possible solution.
Of course, there are several other ways to accomplish that, but `Object.assign` is the most logical solution, in my opinion, making the code easier to maintain on the long run.

Comment: Its needed as part of a project Im working on. I've boiled it down to its essence here.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty fine, perhaps showing the original problem would lead to other possible solutions, though. The best I can guess here is that it can be done in a single loop, not sure whether the "extended" goal would make this piece of code useless, though ;).

Comment: its part of a react app that uses a third party component. i need to create this `newItemsArray` before passing it on to this component as a prop.

Comment: just wondering, why do i need to do Object assign? wouldn't mapping and returning the new object be enough?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty you don't "need" it, I've just decided to use it because it's easy to concatenate objects due to the fact that the `Object.assign` constructor acceps infinite objects as arguments, returning a single merged object. You can also create a single object, check whether IsValid is true, assign the new property and return the new object, but the syntax will be longer. In this way, you can do that in a single line using a ternary operator and Object.assign.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty You're welcome, feel free to read more about Object.assign here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: thanks. one further question. what if i have more conditions besides `IsValid` based on which i add more properties to `newItemsArray`? how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty in that case I would not use object.assign, but I would make the new object, evaluate the conditions adding property and return the new object.